# How to run a Windows Forms application on macOS?

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

Is it possible to run a Windows Forms application (developed using Visual Studio on Windows) on macOS?

What would be needed? Is it free or would I have to purchase something?

Comment: Parallels or Fusion is going to be your answer.  Otherwise you're going to have to re-tool and work with something like Xamarin, Mono,  or such.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it is possible. For example, you can use Mono.

- [What is Mono](http://mono-project.com/What_is_Mono)
- [Porting Winforms Applications to run on Mac OS](http://mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications)

Comment: Hey, After install mono visual studio is required to install or not?

Comment: Mono wont work on ARM Macs, as the macOS `mono` says: `WARNING: The Carbon driver has not been ported to 64bits, and very few parts of Windows.Forms will work properly, or at all`. I cant even run basic winforms app.

Answer (score 5):

The .Net Core is cross platform though it doesn't include winform (maybe it will in the future) or Wpf (definitely won't be cross platform in future).

You can use Xamarin Studio and Mono to make a winform app for mac, though if you want to to use Visual Studio buy Xamarin business license for VS support or make a XNA or a web app. See my answer here [.net core for linux and mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27072599) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to cross-compile using Mono. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/

Answer (score 1):

I've used Xamarin and GTK#, as well as Xamarin for code-behind and XCode for forms design. They both work pretty decently with C# for code-behind stuff.

Just keep in mind that GTK# looks quite clunky and dated when you put it next to a native Mac application.

On the other hand, the object framework for XCode forms (yeah, I know I'm not using the "correct" terminology...) presents a bit of a learning curve, but isn't terribly hard, and Xamarin did a sweet job of integrating the object model into C#, so between the Apple documentation and what Xamarin provides, and er.. from StackOverflow itself, you should be able to produce some neat-looking apps.

Answer (score 1):

[Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) is capable of running some winforms-based Windows applications on Mac OSX.  When it works as intended, all you have to do is install Wine on the Mac, and then it can run your exe.  Of course this won't always work perfectly, and it won't have the polish of a native Mac app, but for simpler Winforms apps it should work.

Answer (score -4):

This is not possible. C# winform applications can only run on Windows.

Comment: You can use Mono and Xamarin Studio to write c# apps that will run on Macs.

Comment: You can't use WinForms per se, but you **can** do GTK# via Xamarin/Mono. Another option is to use Xamarin for the code-behind and XCode for the forms design.

Comment: But if you use X-Code for the forms design will it run on Windows?