# Visual Studio For Mac Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to start working with Windows Forms and I am using Visual Studio for Mac. I already have installed Mono for Visual Studio but I am not sure which type of project I need to choose when I want to create an Windows Forms application or which library I need to import.

EDIT:

Now I created a new Windows Forms Project on Windows and copy paste it on my Mac. I tried to run it but it doesn't open anything and don't return any error.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Windows Form Applications in Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566777/c-sharp-windows-form-applications-in-mac)

Comment: @mjwills look my EDIT at OP

Comment: Still looks like a dupe to me, even with the edit.

Comment: may be https://www.hanselman.com/blog/CrossPlatformGUIsWithOpenSourceNETUsingEtoForms.aspx