# i can't see Window Form Application o my templates on VS 2019/2022 Mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

i am using mac version of VS 2019//2022 i tried to find "Window Form Application" and does not show [where is or how can i use "window form application" template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F1H1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacOS does not support "Windows Form Application". This is only useable on Windows devices. BUT, if you download a Virtuel Machine and run Windows on there you will beable to see Windows Form Application on there.

!Note! At the moment, the new apple silicon M1 chip has very limited options to run VMs. Parrallels is the only one currently, which is not free!

So unless you have the new apple silicon chips, you should be fine running a VM with Windows and you will find Windows Form Applications there.

Comment: Hoooo! thank you so much what i can use instead of Window form application? to se e a Window and see what im coding?

Comment: @NestDe Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566777/how-to-run-a-windows-forms-application-on-macos) can help you?