# How can I run a windows.form app on a mac?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I've been trying to run a **windows.form app** that I made on my PC using C#, to run on my mac, but I don't know how or if its even possible.

I tried using **mono**, but since I am trying to display a histogram its not working.

Here I tried to use the mac version of the **windows.form** that is **cocoa**, but when I create a **cocoa app**, its just filled with errors in the syntax.

[[image: Here is an image of the errors I am getting when I make a cocoa app.]]

===================================================================================================

Also there are 2 more options from the list to choose from, but most people say that the closest one to the **windows.form** app is the **cocoa app**.

[[image: Here are the other 2 options:]]

I want to be able to run the app on a mac, having the same results I was getting on my PC without changing the code of the app.

[[image: Here is the app on my PC.]]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a Windows Forms application on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566777/how-to-run-a-windows-forms-application-on-macos)

Comment: You need to look at .Net MAUI. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: If you're planning to do new development, and therefore modernize your app, I would concur with Donal, .Net MAUI would be a best option than porting your WinForm app to Xamarin.Forms